# how to pass parameter by reference in drupal theme function?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, pass-by-reference

I have drupal module "MyMod"
in hook block i have:

```
case 'view':  
   switch ($delta) {  
   //other cases  
   case 6:  
                $block['cache']=BLOCK_NO_CACHE;  
                $blcok['subject']="";  
                $block['content'] = theme('rss_feeds',$blcok['subject']);  
                return $block;  
}
```

and in MyMod_theme:

```
function MyMod_theme(){
return array(
'rss_feeds' => array(
            'arguments' =>array('Subject' =>NULL),
        ),
);
}
```

and my themes_rss_feeds is:

```
function theme_rss_feeds(&$Subject){...}
```

now i am keep getting this error in admin/reports/event
**Parameter 1 to theme_rss_feeds() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/staging/htdocs/includes/theme.inc on line 656**
how to pass parameter by reference to this theme function??
Thanks for your help

Comment: function theme_rss_feeds($Subject){...}

Answer (score 1):

You can not. It is impossible.

However, you don't want that anyway. Instead, you want to remove the & from the function definition as suggested by Nikit.

Comment: but i need the subject of the block to be defined dynamically based on some conditions... that is why i passed it by ref

Comment: Then move that logic to into hook_block(), theme functions should not contain any logic.  They are only about formatting data. Note that have a typo there ($blcok vs. $block).

Comment: "However, you don't want that anyway." < Why is that so?? What's the issue? Why I need to create a copy of variable passing it to theme when I want to operate on them directly? Just for example: my theme function needs to run hundert time on every page request.